# Insert an image into a MWE of a question or answer

Tags: discussion, design, images, new-users, mwe

Why don't some users add images when posting a question or answer? I believe that, at least for me, sometimes when the question is not very clear, the drawing helps to understand what you want. Do you think it is possible to insert an **automatic alert** between *options, delete, flag, closed*, etc.. where you ask to insert an image?

Comment: Frankly, I am not fully convinced that's a good idea. Which pictures would you suggest for [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/107753/121799), say? I think that there is a significant fraction of questions that do not benefit from pictures. (The others will come with pictures anyway after everybody has read [this post](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7758/121799)... ;-)

Comment: Delete my question? There is not problem.

Comment: No, please don't. I like the discussion (but I am just not 100% convinced that we should go that way).

Comment: @marmot My question was an input. Obviously, if the image is not required, the user will not be asked to insert the image. Okay, I'm not taking it off.

Comment: images are not always necessary and low rep users can not post inline images.

Comment: For example, what image would you add to _this_ question?

Answer (score 1):

Asking for an image to illustrate the problem of an otherwise unclear question is fine.

Someone posting an answer should be allowed to decide for themselves if he/she wants to add an image. Don't harass people with comments to include images if you are not involved in either the question or the answer.

Comment: I asked this question for useful purposes. What does what you wrote mean? I asked to have the possibility to insert an automatic alert if there was a need for an image. I absolutely do not like your answer.

Comment: @Sebastiano You have tagged your question with discussion and this seems to be a valid opinion which expresses that blub is against your proposal.

Comment: @TeXnician I do not want others to agree with me. Often we write to the user to insert an image when needed. In my opinion it should be simply as an automatic message similar to Possible duplicate of ....

Comment: @Sebastiano there is the Meta question https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/430/text-building-blocks that people use to insert comments. You can edit that question to include a comment about images. The comments from that question can be copy-pasted, but you can also use them for auto-comment site plugins such as https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se, which gives you an extra button on the website that allows you to post a predefined comment.

Comment: @Marijn The second link is very important. It is the same that I want. Why is there not in tex.stackexchange? Yet, I not understand because my question is bad. Look the 1st and 2nd comment of my question.

Comment: @Sebastiano I don't use it myself, but I think it works for all Stack Exchange sites, so also for tex.stackexchange.com. After installation of the plugin the button should appear automatically, and you can modify the predefined comments to be customized for TeX.SE.

Comment: @Marijn Do you refer to the button and the empty space where you can enter a comment on completion?

Comment: @Sebastiano I refer to this button: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3Cqp.png that displays a list of predefined comments to choose from. The screenshot is taken from the link I posted earlier (https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se).

Comment: @Marijn I have only add a comment and help.

Comment: @Sebastiano that is correct, you have to install the plugin to get the extra button. See the link for installation instructions.

Comment: @Marijn After almost two years I knew nothing about what you wrote to me. That is why I asked this question.