# Why do some users not vote often for questions or answers?

Tags: discussion, voting

Recently I have observed that several users vote very low. Are there, peraphs, any specific reasons that can be made public?

I think we all have 40 votes, why not use them when there are good questions and good answers?

Comment: related : [Why answer a question that doesn't deserve a vote?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7757/138900)

Comment: A low number of votes is a highly subjective question. To speak rationally, it is necessary to introduce a measure. How would you measure this low voting ratio? By `(total number of votes)/(total number of questions and answers)` ? by `(total reputation)/(number of votes)` ? by `(total number of votes)/(number of connection days)`?
Otherwise?

Comment: @AndréC I think only that: what's remain into our lives? The world is wicked, we must to bring out all the good that we can.

Comment: You should formulate your question in a more positive way so that the people concerned will want to answer you.

Comment: You should not state your feelings in the question, your question should remain neutral. If you want to express your feelings, their place is in an answer. Remember that SE encourages everyone to answer their own questions. https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @downvoter Can I ask why I have a negative vote?

Comment: Well, having voted +1 to your question, I think it is incorrectly asked because you express negative feelings about the attitude you want to understand: « sadly », « selfishness and envy », do you think this is positive? Do you think that will encourage someone to answer?

Comment: I personally will only upvote if I think it is a very interesting question.  I almost never downvote.  There are MANY question where I will not vote at all.

Comment: @James I voted in favour of your comment. I agree with you.

Comment: Personally, I only vote for answers and questions that I understand after compiling the problem code and the answer code. Just because it takes a long time. So I vote moderately, much more than David, but less than you.

Comment: One of the users who disappeared from the site and re-emerged with a new account gave a reason for his low voting behavior: In case the new account will be deleted too, all reputation earned by his upvotes will be lost and may lead to disappointment by some users

Comment: @siracusa Thank you for your comment. I've had a lot of reputation changes when a user unsubscribes from the site. To be honest, I am a user who is not interested in votes and is very interested in understanding LaTeX more and more. Motivating a downvote is a sign of loyalty and respect for each other.

Comment: The sole reason I rarely vote is that high reputation users frequently provides answers that don't address the given question and are based on opinion more than anything else. Anything they say is taken as gospel because of who says it. It's all very off-putting.

Comment: @LaTeXereXeTaL I vote up often because I like it :-))))))))....Now you can see. :-)))

Answer (score 10, accepted):

People vote or don't vote as they see fit, and it's really not for us to be concerned about how much anyone votes. Overall we're a vote-happy bunch, and we also have a tradition of not downvoting excessively.

But whether or not others vote is really not worth worrying about, at least on this site. Both questions and answers generally get enough votes to keep people engaged in the site, which is largely what the purpose of voting is (although it also can help users see the value of an answer).

Comment: Of course, and I agree with your opinion. We are a group and we must always be one without any envy or jealousy. I almost always use my votes when I'm logged in.

Answer (score 13):

Voting is anonymous, so by definition you should not know who voted or why.

You say you notice that some users have low vote scores, but how do you define low?

Vote count has little relevance to anything, my two highest scoring posts have essentially no technical content, and in fact almost no content at all, whereas some that took some days to answer only score one or two votes.

Personally I post far more answers than I vote as I think answering questions is a more useful activity than voting. (nearly 10 thousand answers, and rather less than 3 thousand votes)

Comment: Yet your vote count is higher than your question count. I think you should ask more ;-)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I would ask but (a) I can't find the ask a question button and (b) if I did ask, probably egreg would answer then I'd have to read one of his posts, and that would never do.

Comment: Kind David, I intended the use of 40 votes in one day.

Comment: @Sebastiano I probably use one or two votes a week but why do you care how many votes anyone uses?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Surely and sincerely no. Today, according to the indications of each school in Sicily, the school officially opened. I have almost no time and with all sincerity I have randomly seen the votes assigned after almost three years that I am registered.

Comment: @Sebastiano I do not understand that comment at all, what are you saying "no" to? But it doesn't matter, let this thread stop.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle No, in the sense that I don't care about votes cast of anyone user.

Comment: @Sebastiano so why did you post this question asking about exactly that topic?

Comment: Could you please provide me with a link to "some that took some days to answer". I am a cat, and hence naturally curious to see how such a post could look like. (Or is it just the "plane"? ;-)